# If deploy an ASP.NET Core as a web app to Azure, what is used for hosting?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core out of the box supports hosting in IIS and self-hosting scenarios using the Kestrel and WebListener HTTP servers. Accordingly to web.config / project.json looks like IIS is used, but if so it is not clear for my "why" so, as now IIS is acting just as a reverse proxy and the application itself runs as a separate process using the Kestrel HTTP server.

So the main question is "what" and "why" is used by default, if deploy to Azure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, when you publish to Azure App Services, IIS is used to host your application. As you said, it acts as a [reverse proxy to your application](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#choosing-a-server), which is running Kestrel HTTP server. But IIS does more than that - it also manages the application process through [application pool](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools), which includes or may include:

- restarting the app when web.config changes
- starting the app on the first HTTP request
- running the app as a [specified user](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)
- recycling the app pool (and effectively restarting the app) on [certain conditions](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling)
- starting multiple app processes
- handle [webdeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) (this is what happens when you hit "Publish" in Visual Studio

Comment: For a website deployed to azure app service, can I restrict it to be only used by my company users? Like an intranet? Or is on-prem IIS my only option?

Comment: Yes, you can [configure authentication at App Service level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad). There are different identity providers available, i.e. there's one for Azure Active Directory if your company uses Azure AD.

Comment: This is an alternative to login functionality on the website? If yes, then can I also do role based control? Like admin/manager/staff?

Comment: @qbik 2024Q1 is this still the case? Afaik there is no IIS any more ... it is all Linux VMs?